# Is there any way to fetch the google sheet (gsheet) data in flutter and display realtime updates whenever there is any change in google sheet itself?

Tags: flutter, google-sheets, real-time-data, real-time-clock, flutter-streambuilder

I am developing an application where a list is displayed according to the user input. The list is loading and getting displayed when the application is loaded and whenever the user inputs the data through the text  fields(in the app) and the cells (in the google sheet) gets appended too ( which is what I want). But I would like to be able to get realtime list append in the application whenever any new data is inserted in the google sheet itself. So how do I listen for changes in google sheet everytime there is any change  and update/append the list (in the application) according to it? Currently, whenever the data is inserted in the google sheet itself, the data only gets loaded when I hot restart the application.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Apps Script Triggers? Maybe the function onEdit(e) can help:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

Comment: An `onEdit(e)` [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) cannot use external resources. You need an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.